# Spelling: "hälst" or "hältst"

Tags: word-usage, difference, spelling, conjugation

When asking for feedback, a common sentence is:

> Was hälst / hältst du davon?

How to spell "halten" in this case?

Comment: "hälst" would be from "halsen" if that existed (compare "aufhalsen")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *Was hältst Du davon?*, as it derives from *halten*. *Halten* and its conjugated forms are always spelt the same:

> Ich halte
>   Du hältst
>   Er/Sie/Es hält
>   ...

When used in the context of asking people for their opinion, *Was hälst Du davon* is wrong. It is either a typo or written by a person not knowing the difference between *halten* and *halsen*.